# как парсить код, который пришел на почту

Tags: python, парсер, imap

Я зашел в свой аккаунт почты, взял последнее письмо и не могу понять, как взять от туда код который нужен для регистрации.

```
import imaplib,email


user = 'login'
password = 'password'
imap_url = 'imap.gmail.com'
con = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_url)
con.login(user, password)
con.select('INBOX')
a = con.select("INBOX")[1]
result, data = con.fetch(*a,'(RFC822)')
raw = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
def get_body(raw):
    if raw.is_multipart():
        return get_body(raw.get_payload(0))
    else:
        return raw.get_payload(None , True)

a = con.select("INBOX")[1]
print(get_body(raw))
```

Вот например такой код как [тут](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqum9.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "как тут" это не код а стили, в коде должны быть либо ссылка, либо какоето слово-цифры для ввода на сайте регистратора

Comment: @ganz вот я выделил, вот этот код нужно достать

Comment: на что же должна реагировать программа? на <p>? сомневаюсь что в письме только один абзац. следует искать предшествующее уникальное слово, затем обрезать ненужные символы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю для поиска элемента кода в почтовом сообщении удобно было бы использовать BeautifulSoup, например данный код найдет все элементы <p> в коде почтового сообщения:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml") # вместо lxml можно выбрать другой парсер
raws = soup.findAll("p")
for raw in raws:
    your code here
```